# "Return type of ... is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member"?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to subclass a function `ActionableNotification.java` which reads similar to this:

```
package com.venmo.notifications.notifications;

import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

public abstract class ActionableNotification extends ContextWrapper implements Target {

    @NonNull
    protected abstract String getTrackingNotificationCategory();
    // ...
}
```

The inheriting class reads similar to this

```
class DeclineInsufficientFundsBalanceOnlyCardNotification(context : Context, intent : Intent) : ActionableNotification(context, intent) {

    override fun getTrackingNotificationCategory() = ""
    // ...
 }
```

However, when I try to compile I get this error:

> /Users/kupeek/dev/venmo-android/p2p-app/src/main/java/com/venmo/notifications/notifications/DeclineInsufficientFundsBalanceOnlyCardNotification.kt:
>   (21, 53): Return type of 'getTrackingNotificationCategory' is not a
>   subtype of the return type of the overridden member '@NonNull
>   protected/*protected and package*/ abstract fun
>   getTrackingNotificationCategory(): String defined in
>   com.venmo.notifications.notifications.ActionableNotification'

I don't understand this error message, because the return type of the Kotlin inheriting class is a string, as is the base class?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error and where it appears in the editing window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely sure why this worked, the error went away when I specified the `String` type for the overriding function, instead of relying on type inference:

```
override fun getTrackingNotificationCategory(): String = ""
```

Comment: I tried it out with a minimal example and could not reproduce. Which version of Kotlin are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe annotating the abstract method with the JetBrains annotation `@NotNull` will be better. I found it taking a look a [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#annotating-type-parameters). Hope this may help you.